# Node.js AUTHORIZE endpoints with Oauth2-Google passport

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, passport.js, google-oauth

I'm trying to develop a simple API in node and hiding it behind a google authentification layer, for that I'm using [passport-google-oauth2](https://github.com/mstade/passport-google-oauth2) to enforce a google authentification to do some requests.

```
....
var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth2').Strategy;
var passport = require('passport');

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID:     CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "/oauth2callback",
    passReqToCallback   : true
  },
  function(request, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    console.log("passportUse access Profile ", accessToken);
    done(null, accessToken);
  }

));


app.get('/oauth2callback', 
    passport.authenticate( 'google', { 
        successRedirect: '/notesSuccess',
        failureRedirect: '/notesNotSuccess'
}));

app.get('/notes',
    passport.authenticate('google', { scope: 
    [ 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'] }
), function(req, res) {
  //res.json({notes: "This is your notebook. Edit this to start saving your notes!"})
})


app.get('/notesSuccess', function(req, res) {
  res.json({notes: "This is your notebook. Edit this to start saving your notes!"})
})
app.get('/notesNotSuccess', function(req, res) {
  res.json({notes: "AUTHENTICATION FAIL"})
})


app.get('/notes/API1', function(req, res) {
  res.json({notes: "API1111111"})
})

....
```

The code is working more or less, at `passport.use` I do get all the google plus profile information and a token, so I assume that part is working.

The issue is that when I use the browser to visit `localhost:8080/notes`, I get the results as expected (`/notesSuccess`) when I login, if I'm in a private window I can see the google login page, working well so far.

My problem is if I do a query with postman using the token I was given or a new token with the same scopes I get only the login page (as if I had no Authentification header). If I query `notes/API1` (no Oauth there) it works properly [image]

Any ideas why the headers are not authentifing the query?